# HTML Combining 2 hover effects

Tags: html, css

Hi I am trying to combine 2 hover effects. First hover effect takes places when you hover over the button, the other one is when you hover over the arrow. I am trying to combine those 2 hover effects to take place simultaneously. Could anyone please help me with that? Thank you so much

```css
.btnMain {
    
    padding: 15px 110px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.5s;
    background-size: 200% auto;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #eee;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing:1px;
  margin-top:40px;
  font-size:16px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;

  cursor: pointer;
  moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;

}

.btnMain:hover {
  background-position: 100% 0;
  color:#fff;
  moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  
}
.gradient {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #25aae1, #4481eb, #04befe, #3f86ed);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 15px 0 rgb(65 132 234 / 75%);
}
.arrowIntro {
  color: black;
  font-size:60px;
  margin-left:-2%;
}
.arrowIntro::before {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: -8px;
  content: "";
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
  position: relative;
  top: 16px;
  left: 3px;
}
.arrowIntro:hover {
  color: black;
}

.arrowIntro:hover::before {
  transform: translateX(12px);
}
```

```html
<a href="#kontakt" class="btnMain gradient scrollto">Contact me<a id="arrowIntroId" href="#kontakt" class="arrowIntro"></a></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [CSS Transform Modules](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#transformable-element). Also, a technicality: You were trying to move the arrow on `.arrowIntro:hover` while you wanted it to move on `.btnMain:hover`

```css
.btnMain {
    padding: 15px 110px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.5s;
    background-size: 200% auto;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #eee;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    margin-top:40px;
    font-size:16px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px;
    font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    position: relative;
}

.btnMain:hover {
  background-position: 100% 0;
  color:#fff;
  moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  
}
.gradient {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #25aae1, #4481eb, #04befe, #3f86ed);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 15px 0 rgb(65 132 234 / 75%);
}
.arrowIntro {
  margin-left:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  color: black;
  position:absolute;
  top:7px;
  right:20px;
  transition: transform 500ms ease-in-out 25ms;
}
.arrowIntro::before {
  content: "→";
  font-size:30px;
  color: white;
}
.btnMain:hover .arrowIntro {
  transform: translateX(12px);
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#kontakt" class="btnMain gradient">Contact me<div class="arrowIntro"></div></a>
```

Comment: Thank you, could you please tell me how can I move the arrow to the edge of the button and make it bigger like on example?

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `hover` to the `.btnMain` element:

```
.btnMain:hover .arrowIntro {
  color: black;
}

.btnMain:hover .arrowIntro::before {
  transform: translateX(12px);
}
```

Also, you cannot have an `a` tag within another `a` tag. That's malformed HTML and the first `a` will close at the first closing `a`. I changed that to a span.

```css
.btnMain {
  padding: 15px 110px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
  background-size: 200% auto;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #eee;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.btnMain:hover {
  background-position: 100% 0;
  color: #fff;
  -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.gradient {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #25aae1, #4481eb, #04befe, #3f86ed);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 15px 0 rgb(65 132 234 / 75%);
}

.arrowIntro {
  color: black;
  margin-left: -2%;
}

.arrowIntro::before {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: -8px;
  content: "";
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
  position: relative;
  left: 4px;
}

.btnMain:hover .arrowIntro {
  color: black;
}

.btnMain:hover .arrowIntro::before {
  transform: translateX(12px);
}
```

```html
<a href="#kontakt" class="btnMain gradient scrollto">Contact me<span id="arrowIntroId" class="arrowIntro"></span></a>
```

Comment: Thank you, could you please tell me how can I move the arrow to the edge of the button and make it bigger like on example?